# Window AC fan drip pan full

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning

My AC started to blow out pretty lukewarm air recently, as well as make watery sounds while running. I realized the filter was dirty, and I cleaned the coils, replaced the filter and removed lots of water from the drip pan. I was able to get an improvement in cold air and no watery noise. However, after about 6 hours of use, I started to hear the watery sounds again and noticed the drip pan was full. I imagine the drainage in the unit is clogged. Unfortunately, I live on the 7th floor of a building, so taking the unit out can be quite cumbersome. Are there any methods to fix the problem? Would pouring some bleach into the pan do the trick?

Update: I drained the drainage pan again and saw that the AC unit was regurgitating water.

Comment: have you got a vacuum cleaner than can handle water?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; hope the answer helps. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @Jasen the part of the drain pain which goes under the coils and is accessible to me without taking out is small. Not sure a vacuum would fit

Comment: There are commercial products advertised for cleaning a/c drain lines, e.g. https://www.google.com/shopping/product/17463616094541484041?lsf=seller:8740,store:15015290031536908255&prds=oid:5079959822232651917&q=clean+drain+of+window+ac&hl=en&ei=k65FXaDVDcT0tAWNl6e4Dg&lsft=gclid:CjwKCAjw4ZTqBRBZEiwAHHxpflSKUiF4WCbEwtyQTKlzVZtBNI-rT_Zf1ZnajhBSntGrWGRNTMfjEBoCPUwQAvD_BwE,gclsrc:aw.ds

Comment: My 15 year old GE AC started doing that. irt and crud had blocked the water channel fro cold side to hot side of the unit. Took it out of its chasis, and scraped out as much crud as possible with a putty knife. Then hooked nalgene tubing to faucet, put the AC in the tub and sprayed it down. Avoided electronics as possible. Put soap on cooled intake fins and sprayed that hard. Shiny aluminum! Put the thing back together, and it works better than in the last decade. Moral: crud builds up over time, and you have to clean it out.

Answer (score 1):

For servicing the workings of the whole unit can be taken indoors by undoing fastenings located indoors, leaving just the shell outside, you don't need the power of flight, but you do need to be strong, or gang up on it.

Some designs spray excess condensate water on the condenser coils to improve efficiency, the watery sound may be normal.

Comment: In some units the water level in the drain pan is set so that the condenser fan blades dip into the water and sling it over the coils. This does make noise but evidently improves efficiency.

Comment: I did notice that the water was being slung out of the fans and into the room occasionally.

Comment: The water being slung into the room would be water condensed on the evaporator coils. How long has this unit been in service? It may be necessary to remove the unit and clean it.

Comment: If you look at videos on cleaning window units, you will see how much is involved. Since these units are inexpensive (or were before the trade war) it might be that replacement is the only solution. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmAkZlVErZQ

Comment: the water flinging should be in the outdoor part of the unit, if water is accumulating indoors check the rain that runs to the outdoor tray.